# TS Record type: ...expression of type 'HeaderName' can't be used to index type '{} | Record<HeaderName, string>'

Tags: typescript

The subject line says it all. I have a record type Record<HeaderName, str> and I am trying to add to the Record object by indexing. `headerMap['name'] = 'somename'`

In a typescript class:

```
headerMap: Record<HeaderName, string> | {} = {};
```

Now when I want to pre-populate it, it gets mad at the type but I bend over backwards to convince the compiler it's the right type.

```
(Object.keys(this.required) as HeaderName[]).forEach(k => {
  // iterate through csv headers
  this.csvHeaders.forEach(c => {
      let typedK: HeaderName = 'name' // ok
      if (k.toLowerCase().includes(c.toLowerCase())) {
      this.headerMap[k as HeaderName] = c // error below
      this.headerMap[typedK] = c // also error
      }

    }
  });
});

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'HeaderName' can't be used to index type '{} | Record<HeaderName, string>'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type '{} | Record<HeaderName, string>'.Vetur(7053)
```

But 'name' is one of the types:

```
export type HeaderName =
  | 'name'
  | 'medicaid_id'
  | 'external_id'
...
```

What's more confusing, is that it magically works in the Vue template

```
  <v-row align="center" v-for="(header, headerName) in required" :key="headerName">
    <v-col>
      {{ snakeToTitle(headerName) }}
      <small v-if="!header.is_optional" class="red--text">*</small>
    </v-col>
    <v-col>
      <ih-auto-complete
        v-model="headerMap[headerName]". // THIS JUST WORKS!
        :items="csvHeaders"
        item-value='DOB'
        item-text='text'
        :vid="headerName"
        :required="!header.is_optional"
        :rules="header.is_optional ? '' : 'required'"
      />
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

How do you do an insert into a `Record<K, str> | {}` if not `foo[k] = s`?

It should be valid even accounting for runtime vs compile time, but I must be missing something. BTW I studied other questions and articles and the docs, but they don't seem to address this particular case.

[HeaderName type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6j3r.png)

Comment: I think you are mis-using the `{}` type here. The `{}` type does not only represent an empty object and actually allows any non-nullish values to be assigned. Maybe you want to replace it with `Record<HeaderName, never> | Record<HeaderName, string>`?

Comment: I assume you've typed `headerMap` as `Record<HeaderName, string> | {}` so that the compiler doesn't stop you from assigning `{}` to it. You should use the [`Partial` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) instead and give it a type of `Partial<Record<HeaderName, string>>`.

Comment: I didn't write the code so I have to be careful how I change it but I tried what you suggested and get other errors. We are initializing it as an empty object and then in a Vue for loop, inflating it with all the properties set as undefined, so I'm unclear how to proceed

Comment: I agree with @RyanPattillo. Try to assign the type `Partial<Record<HeaderName, string>>` to `headerMap`. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/w8EG9N).

Comment: That did the trick @Ryan! The linter is happy and it works. My feature pre-populates a multi select form from a csv upload based on best guesses. The algorithm is simple so it's of limited value but typewise and function wise it works so I'm super pleased. Thank you! I understand what Pick does and even though I inherited existing code, I don't see how this would introduce any breaking changes. I think it's the exact right type. Thanks!

Comment: Ah I think I see the error- as it existed, it would have had to be all-or-nothing. I'd have to give it every field or no field, but with partial, it's analogue and gradual. Mutating the value of headerMap would throw an error if it didn't go all the way. I'm wondering how it worked in Vue above, but I'm sure there's a lot of abstract magic under the hood with those type of frameworks and libraries, with babel loaders, and maybe typecasting and generics in order to produce it 'all at once'. Not sure but that was confusing me also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify the problem:

```
type ab = 'a' | 'b';
let headerMap: Record<ab, string> | {};
headerMap['a'];
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"a"' can't be used to index type '{} | Record<ab, string>'.
//   Property 'a' does not exist on type '{} | Record<ab, string>'.
```

Pay attention to the last line of the error: `Property 'a' does not exist on type '{} | Record<ab, string>'.` You defined the `headerMap` type as `{} | ...`, meaning `{}` *MIGHT* be the type of `headerMap`. And, you can not access property 'a' of type `{}`, since `{}` has no properties defined (DIFFERENT from a type with optional properties, more on that later). In order to fix this, let's just remove the `{}` type from the union.

```
declare let headerMapFix: Record<ab, string>;
headerMapFix['a'];
```

Wow! No errors! However, I assume you already thought about this, but didn't go through, because you wanted the headerMap to be by default an empty object:

```
let headerMapFix2: Record<ab, string> = {};
headerMapFix2['a'];
// Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<ab, string>': a, b
```

Error! This is because `Record<ab, string>` is a shorthand for `{a: string, b: string}`, so both properties are mandatory. Ideally, we want a type that represents `{a?: string, b?: string}`. Luckily, there is a type for that: `Partial<Record<ab, string>>`. `Partial` makes all the properties of the wrapped object type optional. Let's try again:

```
let headerMapFix3: Partial<Record<ab, string>> = {};
headerMapFix3['a'];
```

No errors! And of course, you could assign a value to it, `headerMapFix3['a'] = undefined` or `headerMapFix3['a'] = 'some string'`;

Notice how type `{a?: string, b?: string}` is different from type `{}`, because although `a` and `b` can be `undefined` in the former, at least it is declared that the property exists and can be accessed even if it's undefined. `{}` defined no properties to access, which is why you couldn't access any properties on your attempt.